# I'm trying to print this modified parallel array

Tags: c

I'm trying to print modified parallel arrays, these arrays are read from a file and I add another element to them from the keyboard, however, when the program prints the new arrays something goes wrong and I get 000000 as a new element for every array despite the fact that the size of all the arrays has been incremented and I tested it, the new spot is filled with the right new element. here is the code for the 2 functions.
the function that adds elements:

```
void createNewAccount(char names[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], int stdID[MAXSIZE], float phones[MAXSIZE], int registrationYear[MAXSIZE])
{
    int tid, ty;
    float tp;
    char tn[10];
   if(size == MAXSIZE){
       printf("Max size has been reached\n");
   }
   printf("Please enter a student number\n");
   scanf("%d", &tid);
   for(int o=0; o<size; o++){
       if(stdID[o]==tid){
           printf("The student already exists\n");
       }
   }
   size++;
   stdID[size]=tid;
   printf("Please enter a phone number\n");
   scanf("%f", &tp);
   phones[size]=tp;
   printf("Please enter a registration year\n");
   scanf("%d", &ty);
   registrationYear[size]=ty;
   printf("Please enter a name\n");
   scanf("%s", tn);
   strcpy(names[size], tn);
}

and the function that prints is:
void viewList(char names[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], int stdID[MAXSIZE], float phones[MAXSIZE], int registrationYear[MAXSIZE])
{
  for(int j=0; j < size; j++){
           printf("%s %0.2f %d %d\n", names[j], phones[j], stdID[j], registrationYear[j]);
        }
}
```

That problem is fixed now the problem is **tommy 0.00 0 0** the data from the file is:

```
alex 599659008.00 19701112 2010
mark 599232832.00 19702315 2015
tommy 59965680.00 197012415 2020
```

and the result I'm getting is:

```
alex 599659008.00 19701112 2010
mark 599232832.00 19702315 2015
tommy 59965680.00 197012415 2020
tommy 0.00 0 0
```

Comment: Please turn the code fragments into a [mre] which demonstrates your observation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is you are doing your size++ too early.  If size starts at the number of entries you currently have, you are writing to the element following the one you intend to in createNewAccount().  Shift the size++ to the bottom of that function and things should work.

Comment: now i discovered im get something weird, the file contains `alex 599659008.00 19701112 2010
mark 599232832.00 19702315 2015
tommy 59965680.00 197012415 2020`
and when I print it without adding anything it prints this:
`alex 599659008.00 19701112 2010
mark 599232832.00 19702315 2015
tommy 59965680.00 197012415 2020
tommy 0.00 0 0`
why does it print this **tommy 0.00 0 0**

Comment: @Azibc Edit your question, provide the file and the way you retrieve data from it.

Comment: Impossible to debug without seeing the code.  I suggest you add a debugging printf() to your createNewAccount() routine to show which array element you are adding to, and a debugging printf() to your viewList() routine to show which element you are printing.  I suspect the bug will then be obvious

Answer (score 0):

All i had to do is to increase the size of tn from 10 to 50.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).